# Probability: Tetrahedron

Tags: probability

In a random sample a weighted tetrahedron is rolled and it is marked which one of the side faces 1, 2, 3, 4 occurs (that is, is against the floor after the roll). It has been observed in long sample series that the ratio of the numbers of occurred side faces is 2 : 3 : 4 : 5.

Determine the sample space and the frequency function which describe the random sample.

How should I proceed with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have for each $i\in\Omega =\{1,2,3,4\}$: $$P(X=i) = (i+1)\cdot p$$

where $0\leq p\leq 1$. Since $$\sum P(X=i) = 1\implies 2p+3p+4p+5p=1 \implies p = {1\over 14} $$

Answer (score 1):

The sample space is just the four possible outcomes.  Can you calculate the probability of each event based on the ratio of their appearances?

Answer (score 0):

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space with $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4\}$, $\mathcal F = \mathcal P(\Omega)$, and 
\begin{align}
\mathbb P (\{1\}) &= \frac17\\
\mathbb P (\{2\}) &= \frac3{14}\\
\mathbb P (\{3\}) &= \frac27\\
\mathbb P (\{4\}) &= \frac5{14}.
\end{align}
Since $\{1\}$, $\{2\}$, $\{3\}$, and $\{4\}$ are the atoms of $\Omega$, specifying their probabilities defines $\mathcal P$ for all subsets of $\Omega$.